# What is the use case of summarize functionality with/without ADDCOLUMNS?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

What is the difference between the following DAX approaches to summarize?

Option 1:

```
EVALUATE
ADDCOLUMNS (
    SUMMARIZE (
        Sales,
        'Date'[Year],
        Product[Color]
    ),
    "Total Quantity", CALCULATE ( SUM ( Sales[Quantity] ) )
)
```

Option 2:

```
EVALUATE
    SUMMARIZE (
        Sales,
        'Date'[Year],
        Product[Color],
"Total Quantity", CALCULATE ( SUM ( Sales[Quantity] ) )
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need the calculate in your second example. Regardless, the reason to prefer the ADDCOLUMNS() version is because it is faster. The only reason to use the second version is:

> when you apply filters over columns that are not included in the
> grouped column and then calculate the extended column expression using
> data coming from related tables, the filter context will be different
> between SUMMARIZE vs. ADDCOLUMNS.

Full details can be found here: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/best-practices-using-summarize-and-addcolumns/